# Java Collection, Set, Map or Array to hold unique sorted non blank strings

Tags: java

I am fairly new to java and would like a container that I can use to hold strings that are not empty and have them sorted.

So far, I have mostly been using ArrayList, but this seems a bit limited for this case.

Thanks

Comment: Empty like a zero-length, empty like only whitespaces inside or empty like `Null`?

Comment: zero length and only whitespaces.  I have no quarrel with `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TreeSet` or `TreeMap`, depending on your requirements. Both are collections that accept unique elements and keep them sorted.

Comment: Surely just TreeSet? There is no suggestion that a map is required.

Comment: Thanks Luigi.  I have had a quick read and I think the `TreeSet` is the one for me.  I just need to figure out a way to either remove empty string or prevent it from being put there in the first place.

Comment: @RobMason you could use `if (!yourString.isEmpty()) { set.add(yourString); }`

Comment: @Bohemian I tend to recommend `Map` along with `Set` since you cannot retrieve elements from a `Set`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, maps are not collections.

Comment: @kocko the fact that `Map` doesn't extend `Collection` interface doesn't mean it's not a Java Collection. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html

Comment: And you can with a map? Do you mean `map.put(str, str)` then `map.values().get(i)`?

Comment: Actually a Map is *not* a Collection. No question about it. However, Map is part of the Collections *Framework*.

Comment: @Bohemian well, `String` is not a good example of it, but when I need to store particular classes, it becomes handy in case I don't want/need to create a class that acts as the key e.g. the `hashCode` and `equals` method of my class is based in two `String`s and an `int` which I can fulfill later and still I want/need to store a small cache of this class to use in a single method w/o using a cache library.

Answer (score 2):

A Set is what you want, as the items in it have to be unique.
As the Strings should be sorted you'll need a TreeSet.
As for the non blank Strings you have to override the insertion methods like this:

```
Set<String> sortedSetOfStrings = new TreeSet<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean add(String s) {
        if(s.isEmpty())
            return false;

        return super.add(s);
    }
};
```

EDIT: Simplified thanks to Peter Rader's comment.

Comment: As you said String implements Comparable. From the TreeSet javadoc.

Constructs a new, empty tree set, sorted according to the
natural ordering of its elements. Or did I understand wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help.  Here is what I eventually came up with, using `TreeSet` and apache commons `StringUtils`.  My Input is a CSV String so, I didn't use the check on the input.

```
            String csvString = "Cat,Dog, Ball, Hedge,, , Ball, Cat"
            String[] array = StringUtils.split((String) csvString, ",");

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = array[i].trim(); //Remove unwanted whitespace
            }

            set = new TreeSet<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
            set.remove("");     //Remove the one empty string if it is there
```

`set` now contains: `Ball,Cat,Dog,Hedge`

Comment: You don´t need StringUtils for that. Java´s String[] array = "a,b".split(","); is just as good for that. Nevertheless StringUtils works just as well.